# Programmer Handedness in profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

This is a bit of an odd request, but I've been curious about this for a few years. When I was studying Computer Science in college, I noticed almost all of my classmates were right handed, even more than normal in society. I remember actively counting one day through four classes of roughly 30 people (all computer science) only 4 left handed people, myself included. Is programming something that is conceptually harder for lefty's or am I just paranoid? So I figured, why not let people state their handedness on their stack overflow profiles and we'll let the awesome power of the internet and the new stack api figure out if there is any odd trends going on here. Particular interest to me would be how favorite languages would break down by handedness (spoiler, I bet lefty's lean more toward functional).

One sidenote, I noticed that certain aspects of programming came quite naturally to me compared to my classmates, like multi-threading, but recursion and efficient algorithms were much harder for me personally. Thoughts, Observations?

Comment: 4 left-handers out of 30 individuals seems about average to me; or do you mean *roughly 30 people **each**?*

Comment: 4 left handers out of 4 classes of 30, so 4 out of 120.

Comment: Gripping handed. Definitely. Or seriously: I am right hand-, but left eye- and leg-dominate. I bat, bowl, golf and play tennis right handed, but box southpaw and ride boards of all kinds goofy foot. So, where do I fit in? The lesson here is: people are weirder and more complicated than those theories like to make out.

Comment: @dmc I don't think I have a dominating leg. If so I've never noticed. I'm right randed and left eyed though.

Comment: I am left handed. Last time I checked, left handed people make up 10% of the population. You also have ambidextrous people.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that quite a few programmers are also actively involved in things which would be considered "artistic" such as painting, music, writing, etc. I mean a ton of programmers out there have active blogs.

I think it's probably coincidental because you need both sides to do programming. You need to be capable of thinking logically to solve the problem at hand and think creatively to solve the problem at hand **well** (as in, clean code).

Now for your actual feature request. I would rather recommend(with approval possibly?) creating a community wiki poll. This is not something that belongs in the SO engine for sure.

Comment: Yup, a poll would be in order.

Comment: Some parts of music are much more "artistic" than others... e.g. I find original composition difficult, but reading sheet music and learning instruments quite easy, as I view them as just another language and tool respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting - I would have said there is a larger proportion of left-handers amongst my colleagues than in the population as a whole.  However, that is a completely unsubstantiated quasi-observation; I've not tried to measure the numbers.  I'm left-handed, FWIW (though I throw right-handed and kick right-footed).

Answer (score 1):

I may be biased as I am a left hander but the most successful projects I've worked on had a high proportion of left handers. I always notice it at interviews.

This article seems to suggest that left handers have more connectivity between left and right hemispheres so they get the benefit of being logical and creative.

http://psy.rin.ru/eng/article/124-101.html

Maybe rather than a poll we should find out handedness for people like Linus etc?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand biology, "left-brained" people tend to think more logically and less creatively. Also, if I'm correct, the left side of the brain controls the right side of the body.

The inverse of this leads me to believe that the majority of right-handed people are left-brained, which would follow closely to mind of a programmer and thus, most programmers would be right handed.

Of course, I have no facts whatsoever to back this up.

Comment: Programming is not simply logical thinking, it involves a lot of creativity and intuition as well, which is right-hemisphere activity.